# Swift - date formatter returns unwanted time

Tags: swift, date

If I convert "2019-01-01T00:00:00+0000" to a date, I would like the date to be the date in the string - January 1, 2019. And if I calculate the number of seconds in the time portion, I would like the result to be zero.

The problem is, when I convert my string into a date, it is stored in the UTC timezone. My locale is set to "en_US_POSIX", and my time zone is set to current. My date formatter uses "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ". I know that the final Z means UTC, but I can't seem to figure out the correct field symbol to get the results I want.

```
func convertToDate(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
   dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
   let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
      else {
         print("DATE ERROR:", dateString)
         return Date()
      }
   return date
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert the date string (which is in UTC time) to a local date (no matter what the user's current timezone happens to be) with the same date at midnight? So all users will get January 1, 2019 at midnight, regardless of their current timezone?

Comment: And no, the final `Z` in the date format does not mean UTC. It means "parse the timezone specified in the date string". In this case, the string itself specifies the UTC timezone via the `+0000` at the end.

Comment: Good question. The app is for one company in one time zone so I guess the answer is yes, all users should get January 1, 2019, regardless. And I'll have to recheck my source regarding the Z. I found a great article online titled, "Understanding Dates" but apparently, I haven't quite absorbed all of that information yet. (The article was greatly appreciated, however.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure that the date strings you wish to parse will always end with a timezone in the form `+XXXX` then you can trim off that timezone from the string and then parse the remaining string as local time.

```
func convertToDate(_ dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let minusTZ = String(dateString.dropLast(5)) // Assume the string ends with a +9999 timezone
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: minusTZ)
    return date
}
```

This will give you a local date with the same date and time in the original string regardless of the timezone of the original string.